# Отследить добавление (появление) нового файла в папке? (java)

Tags: java, файлы, события

Пишу проект на java. Программа должна просмотреть папку и найти кол-во файлов в ней. После этого если добавляются новые файлы, то происходит какое-то действие. (Использую Windows, проект собираю maven'ом в NetBeans).

Подскажите может есть какие-то библиотеки или алгоритм, при котором можно найти новые файлы в папке? Например узнать, что этот файл только что был добавлен в эту папку.

Comment: в java наверное есть какой то аналог FileSystemWatcher

Comment: [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) - гуглится за 5 секунд.